# how to append if found, and replace if not found at all? (xml find.each loop)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to search a string value in an xml file, and then append to a div if the string value is found. If not found at all, then I need to display an error text in the same div that the search term was not found.

This is basically supposed to be a search page which loads the searched items into div content.

Currently my content is loading fine. The searched term if found loads all the corresponding divs from the xml, but I've been unable to display an error if the search term was not found.

### My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<items xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <item>
        <animal_id>1_1</animal_id>
        <animal_title>Sparrow</animal_title>
        <animal_generic>Birds 1</animal_generic>
        <animal_category>Birds</animal_category>
        <animal_code>a1</animal_code>
        <animal_img>http://i.imgur.com/R0754lr.png</animal_img>
        <animal_url>1_1_Animals1.html</animal_url>
    </item>
    <item>
        <animal_id>1_2</animal_id>
        <animal_title>Crow</animal_title>
        <animal_generic>Birds 2</animal_generic>
        <animal_category>Birds</animal_category>
        <animal_code>b2</animal_code>
        <animal_img>http://i.imgur.com/R0754lr.png</animal_img>
        <animal_url>1_2_Animals2.html</animal_url>
    </item>
    <item>
        <animal_id>1_3</animal_id>
        <animal_title>Parrot</animal_title>
        <animal_generic>Birds 3</animal_generic>
        <animal_category>Birds</animal_category>
        <animal_code>c3</animal_code>
        <animal_img>http://i.imgur.com/R0754lr.png</animal_img>
        <animal_url>1_3_Animals3.html</animal_url>
    </item>
</items>
```

### HTML

```
<div class="list-h">

</div>
```

### Javascript

```
var s_string = 'bird';

$.ajax({
    url: 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27854284/Stuff/Online/XML_animals.xml', // name of file you want to parse
    dataType: "xml",

    success: function parse(xmlResponse){

    $(xmlResponse).find("item").each(function() {
        var pr_id = $(this).find("animal_id").text();
        var p_title = $(this).find("animal_title").text();
        var p_category = $(this).find("animal_category").text();
        var p_code = $(this).find("animal_code").text();
        var p_img = $(this).find("animal_img").text();
        var p_url = $(this).find("animal_url").text();
        var p_gen_name = $(this).find("animal_generic").text();

        var p_xml_string = p_title + p_gen_name, results_string = '', error;
        if(s_string)
        var s_string2 = s_string.replace("%20"," ");
        //console.log(p_xml_string + s_string2);

        if(p_xml_string.toLowerCase().indexOf(s_string2) > -1){
            //console.log("FOUND : " + p_title);

            results_string = '<div class="item"><div class="item-h"><a class="item-anchor" href="' + p_url + '"><div class="item-image"><img class="item-image-first" src="' + p_img + '" alt=""><div class="item-meta"><h2 class="item-title">' + p_title + '</h2><span class="item-arrow"></span></div></div></a></div></div>';
                found_string = true;  //// KEEP VALUES = TRUE OR FALSE IN AN ARRAY...GLOBAL ARRAY, AND THEN SEARCH THAT ARRAY FOR TRUE. IF ALL FALSE, SHOW ERROR.
            }

        if(found_string){
        $('.list-h').append(results_string);
            $('<div id="error_div"></div>').text("found");
        }
        }); //xmlResponse .each function end.


        },  error: function(){console.log('Error: Animals info xml could not be loaded.');}

        });



// START OF NOT FOUND SEARCH SCRIPT
    $(window).load(function(){
    var error_found = $('#error_div').text(); console.log(error_found);
        setTimeout(function(){ 
        if(error_found != 'found'){
        var results_string = '<center>Your Search Query "<b>' + $.url().param('q').replace("%20"," ") + '" was not found!</b> Maybe you entered an invalid search query.</center>';
        $('.list-h').append(results_string); } 
        }, 0);
    });
// END OF NOT FOUND SEARCH SCRIPT
```

And here's the js fiddle with complete XML url: http://jsfiddle.net/mohitk117/B89Ms/

Please could someone help me out regarding this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some changes may sort out your problem

Add a div in your `html`

```
<div id="error_div"></div>
```

Change below code

```
if (s_string) var s_string2 = s_string.replace("%20", " ");
//console.log(p_xml_string + s_string2);
if (p_xml_string.toLowerCase().indexOf(s_string2) > -1) {
```

to

```
var s_string2='';
if (s_string) s_string2 = s_string.replace("%20", " ");
if (s_string2 && p_xml_string.toLowerCase().indexOf(s_string2) > -1) {
```

Change `found_string` code like,

```
if (found_string) {
   $('.list-h').append(results_string);
   $('#error_div').text("found");
}
```

Optionally add css for `error_div`

```
#error_div {
    color:red;
}
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/B89Ms/1/)

**Updated** `success` code

```
    var found_string = false; // define found_string globally
    $(xmlResponse).find("item").each(function () {
        var pr_id = $(this).find("animal_id").text();
        var p_title = $(this).find("animal_title").text();
        var p_category = $(this).find("animal_category").text();
        var p_code = $(this).find("animal_code").text();
        var p_img = $(this).find("animal_img").text();
        var p_url = $(this).find("animal_url").text();
        var p_gen_name = $(this).find("animal_generic").text();

        var p_xml_string = p_title + p_gen_name,
            results_string = '',
            error;
        var s_string2 = '';

        if (s_string) s_string2 = s_string.replace("%20", " ");
        if (s_string2 && p_xml_string.toLowerCase().indexOf(s_string2) > -1) {
            //console.log("FOUND : " + p_title);
            results_string = '<div class="item"><div class="item-h"><a class="item-anchor" href="' + p_url + '"><div class="item-image"><img class="item-image-first" src="' + p_img + '" alt=""><div class="item-meta"><h2 class="item-title">' + p_title + '</h2><span class="item-arrow"></span></div></div></a></div></div>';
            found_string = true; //// KEEP VALUES = TRUE OR FALSE IN AN ARRAY...GLOBAL ARRAY, AND THEN SEARCH THAT ARRAY FOR TRUE. IF ALL FALSE, SHOW ERROR.
        }
        if (found_string) { // if found then append in list
            $('.list-h').append(results_string);
        }

    }); //xmlResponse .each function end.
    if (found_string) { // if found then empty error div
        $('#error_div').text("");
    } else { // else show error text or not found
        $('#error_div').text("not found");
    }
```

Updated **[Found Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/B89Ms/4/)** and **[Not Found Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/B89Ms/3/)**

Comment: How do I remove the error div if the string has been found? Currently in your jsfiddle, the "found" is still showing even if the string was found!

Comment: See updated demos for [found](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/B89Ms/4/) and [not found](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/B89Ms/3/)

Comment: Thankyou!! That displayed the error & the found divs perfectly!! :D

Comment: Hey, for anyone viewing this answer, just change `s_string.replace("%20", " ");` to `s_string.toLowerCase().replace("%20", " ");` for search strings with a capslock, for example: "Sparrow" with a capital S, would require to be changed to small s, in javascript, otherwise it won't be found.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit uncertain of how everything fits together because the javascript code is not self-explanatory. But, can you start by addressing this issue here...?

```
    if(s_string)
    var s_string2 = s_string.replace("%20"," ");
    //console.log(p_xml_string + s_string2);

    if(p_xml_string.toLowerCase().indexOf(s_string2) > -1){
```

`s_string2` variable is out of scope when you use it in this expression...

```
if(p_xml_string.toLowerCase().indexOf(s_string2) > -1){
```

What were you trying to do there? The expression above will always evaluate to false because `s_string2` is undefined. In other words, whatever processing you are doing inside that `if` block will never be reached

Again, this variable is instantiated and disposed at the very same time...

```
 if(s_string)
     var s_string2 = s_string.replace("%20"," "); //<--- This variable's lifecycle ends here
```

and, this expression will always be false until you address the variable issue above...

```
if(p_xml_string.toLowerCase().indexOf(s_string2) > -1)
```

Comment: Well, I'm trying to send the search string from other pages to this search.html page with parameter 'search.html?q=birds' (birds is the searched string) so if there's a space, like `carnivorous animals` in the url it'll be `q=carnivorous%20animals` so I was only trying to remove the `%20` and replace it with a `SPACE`. Why is `s_string2` out of scope? If you check the jsfiddle, the divs are loading correctly! `if(s_string)` is only checking if any query has been passed at all or not, for example: 'search.html?q=' would be false for that if condition.

Comment: `s_string2` is out of scope because it is declared within a different context...if you haven't noticed, this expression `if(p_xml_string.toLowerCase().indexOf(s_string2) > -1)` will always evaluate to false because `s_string2` is undefined...

Comment: Thankyou Leo! I only wanted to display an error if the string was not found, and I found the solution via Rohan's answer! Thanks again!